# Different values in same colum, how to retrieve data

Tags: sql

I have a Wordpress-based SQL-database buildt on custom fields.

The following 3 columns is connected: post_id, meta_key and meta_value.

The meta_key can be "name" and "age", while the meta_value can be "John" and "40".
Would look like this:

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ POST_ID ║ META_KEY ║ META_VALUE ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║     559 ║ name     ║ John       ║
║     559 ║ age      ║ 40         ║
║     699 ║ name     ║ John       ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

I need to count everyone whose name is John and age is 40. Is this possible with a select-statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) totalCOunt
FROM
(
  SELECT post_ID
  FROM table1
  WHERE (meta_key = 'Name'  AND meta_value = 'John') OR
        (meta_key = 'Age'  AND meta_value = '40')
  GROUP BY post_ID
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) s
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c442/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31ac0/1)

Comment: It won't work, because the name/age is a value of the column "meta_key".

Comment: Hmm.. Getting close, but with this if I have many Johns I still get those who is not 40 :-/

Comment: I mean, if you add someone who's name "Bob" to the same post_id with the age 40.

Comment: can you give me sample records of what you have? `:D`

Comment: Problem still seems to be that it returns posts where both name and age is represented, but the age might belong to someone else :/

Answer (score 0):

I stole your fiddle john.

```
SELECT  a.meta_value,b.meta_value,count(*)
FROM TABLE1 a
inner join TABLE1 b on b.Post_ID = a.Post_ID
                  and a.meta_key = 'name'
where b.meta_key = 'age'
and a.meta_value = 'John'
and b.meta_value = 40
group by a.meta_value,b.meta_value
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebebb/2

Oh yeah I also assumed the post id was what related a name to an age otherwise I think this would take magic to know what goes with what.